# What are the advantages/disadvantages of using Oracle Auto Segment Space Management?

Tags: database, oracle, oracle10g

I've been looking at switching many of our Oracle tablespaces over to use automatic segment space management.

I know that it helps by managing freelists and the like, but I'm curious if anyone has seen any disadvantages to using this option?  Major advantages?

Our environment is somewhat a hybrid between an OLTP and Data Warehousing where some tables are large and fairly static, to tables upwards of 700M rows with heavy updates and partitioning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The essential point of `ASSM` is that `Oracle` chooses `PCTUSED` dynamically and automatically for you and you don't have control over it anymore.

`PCTUSED` tells how much space should be in a `non-free` block to become `free` again (`free` here means able to accept newly inserted rows)

If you never fine-tuned this parameter for your database, then you will probably benefit from `ASSM`.